# Remove English words from Arabic string

Tags: python-3.x

Given a string containing a mixture of Arabic and English, I want to remove any English char or word from it, leaving only an Arabic sentence. The following code doesn't work. How can I modify it?

```
import string

text = 'انا أحاول أن أعرف من انت this is not'
maintext = ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch not in set(string.punctuation))
text = filter(lambda x: x==' ' or x not in string.printable , maintext)
print(text)
```

Thank you

Comment: Regex patterns, like [a-zA-Z] for all latin letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `re.sub` here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

text = 'انا أحاول أن أعرف من انت this is not'
output = re.sub(r'\s*[A-Za-z]+\b', '' , text)
output = output.rstrip()
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
انا أحاول أن أعرف من انت
```

As a side note, we capture possible leading whitespace in the regex pattern `\s*[A-Za-z]+`, because we don't want to cause two Arabic words which surrounded an English word to become fused together.  But, this leaves the possibility of trailing whitespace on the RHS, so we call `rstrip()` to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version:

```
import string
import re

text = 'انا أحاول أن أعرف من انت this is not'
maintext = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]', '', text)
print(maintext)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers suggest using REGEX, but you can do this without regex and just the ascii letters from string module

```py
import string

text = 'انا أحاول أن أعرف من انت this is not'
text = "".join([char for char in text if char not in string.ascii_letters]).strip()
print(text)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
انا أحاول أن أعرف من انت
```